# how to avoid undefined data when getting data from redux using useSelector?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-functional-component

Please let me know how to get data conditionally (if exists) when working with useSelector in reactJs component. Sometimes the required data is not available untill a certain component renders first.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` to safely access a property on an object that might not exist.  You can combine this with the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) `||` to set a default value if the `user` or `user_name` is not set.

```js
const user_name = useSelector(state => state.user?.user_name) || ''
```